# Отфильтровать по категориям в express + mondodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

req.body.categories приходит массив выбранных категорий например [{name: 'vue'}, {name: 'react'}...] как можно найти и вывести все посты с такими категориями? В моём коде я думал обойти циклом forEach но у меня появляеться ошибка в консоли `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

```
exports.filter = async function(req, res) {
try {
if (req.body.categories.length) {
  let postsArr = []
  req.body.categories.forEach(item => {
    const post = await Post.find({ category: item.name });
    if (post) {
      postsArr.push(post)
    }
  })

  res.status(200).send(postsArr);
}
} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
}
```

};

Comment: Первая мысль, что все из-за конструкции try catch. Попробуй или без нее, или внутри try самоиспольняющуюся функцию async await.

Comment: без try catch всё равно не работает, тут скорее всего нужно както делать через Promise.all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это ошибка отображается из-за того, что у вас `await` находится не в `async` функции:

```
req.body.categories.forEach(item => { // тут функция не async
```

Если вы хотите по одной категории запрашивать из БД, можно сделать что-то такое:

```
for (let item of req.body.categories) {
    const post = await Post.find({ category: item.name });
    if (post) {
        postsArr.push(post);
    }
}
```

Но можно сделать вообще по другому, запрашивать все нужную информацию сразу:

```
if (req.body.categories.length) {
    let names = req.body.categories.map(category => category.name);
    let postsArr = await Post.find({ category: { "$in": names } });

    res.status(200).send(postsArr);
}
```

Comment: То есть, дело в forEach, что там есть коллбэк, а это тоже функция?

Comment: `=>` - это оператор "стрелочной" функции, почти эквивалентен `categories.forEach(function(item) { ... })`, т.к. да это функция, а она не помечена `async`